# Java Palm brown leaf

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, leaves, indoors, palm

I have had a Java Palm for around 1 year. Indoor. Recently, about 1 month ago, I am observing an abnormal amount of leaves turning brown, gradually. I normally water the plant couple times a week, 1 time slightly, another time thoroughly and let it drain well.

The plant is growing new leaves periodically but some are already turning brown by the tips.

Any idea of what might be happening? Is this information enough for the community to help?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you add a closeup picture of the underside of a leaf?

Answer (score 1):

Could be a problem with dry air and/ or under watering. Spritz the leaves once a day. It will certainly help. Palms are used to tropical climates and don't take well to sudden changes in temperature too. Lower leaves will slowly brown naturally and you can just cut them off.

Answer (score 1):

They do this when lacking water.

You want to give them water every other day but also be careful not to overwater.   I know catch-22, but just don't over-water, drenching them.
I am in zone 5 and just took mine out of my garage to move outside for summer. They did absolutely great over winter, and pretty much went dormant (as much as tropical plants can lol).

But yes lack of water and remembering to change out the soil beginning of every year as I did after a week of being outside and I give mine fish fertilizer, very stinky but they love.